# xwiki export page option for HTML

Tags: xwiki

created some pages and when export that page in PDF then PDF page option page comes but when export it as HTML no HTML page option comes.is there any way to get this.[html export page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zs5w.png)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML export offers currently the same minimal user interface as the XAR export, which is to select the list of pages and then to click the appropriate export button, exactly as you have shown in your screenshot: https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/UserGuide/Features/Exports#HHTMLExport There are currently no other export options for these types of formats. Maybe in the future.

PDF export, on the other hand, has this intermediary options screen https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/UserGuide/Features/Exports#HPDFExport that is specific only to this type of export as it contains options specific to the fact that the page(s) are exported and merged into as single PDF file. These options make little sense for the other type of export formats (XAR or HTML).

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: okey.is it possible to create some extension or macro to customize the HTML export,if yes which language(velocity,groovy...) should i use to design the funcationality.